# Should I use the array in this way?

Tags: php, arrays

I have a function like this:

```
$arrayz = fetch_array_from_somewhere();
if($arrayz) {
   $arrayz['foo'] = 12;
}
```

Now if `array` ends up empty it will be false, and if it has someting but I don't care what it has because I am just, for example, adding more data to that array; is it ok to use `if()` statement this way?

Same question for object arrays (just $arrayz->foo = 12 instead)?

Or should I use empty()?

Edit 1: Just to clarify when I say object array I mean: Array of objects.

So I know that I will always get an array. I don't care what is in it.

Edit 2:

So in conclusion I should only use this form if I KNOW that I will get an array, either full or `array()`, either if it is an regular array or an object array (array of objects).

But if I think that I will get something besides that I should use aditional checks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `fetch_array_from_somewhere` only return array, then you could do this. An empty array is evaluated as `false`.

For object, you can't do this, object is always evaluated as `true` except SimpleXML objects created from empty tags.

Comment: This answers my question well, so if object is return it is true, for the specific purpose this suits me.

Answer (score 2):

You can use your one or you can use any of the following:

```
if(sizeof($array)){
    // has array values
}
```

This will check the size of the array. If it returns 0 then its empty - I like to use this (or count below) because it is the correct way to check the actual amount of array values, e.g. `if(sizeof($array) > 2){ // more than 2 array values }`.

```
if(count($array)){
    // has array values
}
```

This is the same as above.

```
if(!empty($array)){
    // its not empty
}
```

This will check to see if its empty (i.e. no array values) or if its not set at all (same as `isset()`)

**But wait...**

```
if(is_array($array)){
    // its an array
}
```

This is always good to throw in the mix. Strings, numbers, objects and anything else that is not an array will match all of the above. You want to make sure that what you're dealing with is **actually** an array before you start trying to access it as such.

So, this is usually my code:

```
if(is_array($array) && sizeof(array)){
   // manipulate
}
else {
  // isn't an array or doesn't have any values.
}
```

Comment: This also answers my question in an more indirect way and teaches me. If I could I would give both you and xdazz accept.

Comment: Hey, at least you learnt something :) Its not all about the points! :p

Answer (score 1):

using `empty()` is the way to go. boolean checks are supposed to be used if the function returns boolean.

Comment: If it is no bother, can you explain why?

Comment: coz when you check `if($arrayz)` it only checks if the array is empty, but using the function empty() checks if the array is isset and empty. Same goes with checking for objects, unless you want to check for a specific value as in `if($arrayz->foo == 12)`

Comment: -1. `if (!$foo)` and `if (empty($foo))` are exactly the same if there is no possibility that `$foo` may not exist - which is the case in the question. The bit you aren't doing is verifying that `$foo` is an array

Comment: what if the function has an error and doesn't return? Checking for `is_array` doesn't work if on failure from the function, it returns an empty array.

Comment: lots of assumptions there. In the q `$foo` is always defined - it is either false or a not-empty array. There is no difference or benefit with replacing `if ($foo)` with `if (!empty($foo))`. Not sure what you mean by "has an error and doesn't return" if there is no explicit return statement, `$foo` would simply be null. The main benefit/reason to use `empty` is where it may or may not be set and you just want to be sure it IS set and with a truthy value. It doesn't cause a problem to use empty - it's a matter of style in the context of the question, but it doesn't bring benefit, hence -1

Comment: you are assuming that the function would return false (which is good programming, but need not be implemented)

Comment: so the OP edited his question, and he knows its gonna return an array (empty or otherwise), so conclusion, it doesn't matter `if($array)` or `if(empty($array))`

Comment: interesting discussion, thanks!